# Getting failure percentage for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+------------+---------+------------+--------------+------+
| dt         | status  | code       | arena        | cnt  |
+------------+---------+------------+--------------+------+
| 2016-01-01 | failure | AB         | kingdom1     |    2 |
| 2016-01-01 | success | AB         | kingdom1     |   16 |
| 2016-01-01 | failure | CD         | kingdom1     |   50 |
| 2016-01-01 | success | CD         | kingdom1     |  662 |
| 2016-01-01 | failure | EF         | kingdom1     |  131 |
| 2016-01-01 | success | EF         | kingdom1     |  622 |
```

**SQL Query :**

```
select DATE(created) as dt, status, code, arena,count(status) as cnt
from game_table
where some_condition
group by dt, code, status)
```

**Requirement :**

I need to find failure percentage of `code`, `arena` wise but what I tried is returning 100% failure for all (*baaaaad coder*).

```
+------------+---------+------------+--------------+------+
| dt         | status  | code       | arena        |failed|
+------------+---------+------------+--------------+------+
| 2016-01-01 | failure | AB         | kingdom1     | 11.1 |
| 2016-01-01 | failure | CD         | kingdom1     | 7.02 |
| 2016-01-01 | failure | EF         | kingdom1     | 17.4 |
```

**I tried :**

```
select dt, cnt/sum(cnt) as p, status, code, arena 
from (
  select DATE(created) as dt, status, code, arena,count(status) as cnt
  from game_table
  where some_condition
  group by dt, code, status
 ) as inner_t
group by dt, code, status;
```

Comment: Please show your expected result rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : added

Comment: Good. Code GH is not in the results. kingdom2 isn't either. Is this on purpose? If so, what is the reson for them not being selected? And code AB should have a quote of 2 / 18 * 100 = 11.1, right?

Comment: And what if there were an additional record for AB on 2016-01-02? Would you want a separate result row for this code/date combination?

Comment: GH was to much to calculate manually...i removed it from original post as well...and 11.1..corrected that as well!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : no....there would only have `failure` and `success` columns, no other record!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be to understand GROUP BY properly. It only means "show me one result row per ______". You want one result row per `code` it seems, so you `group by code`. If you want a line per `code` and `arena`, you `group by code, arena`. For the fields not in `GROUP BY` decide which aggregate to show, e.g. the *minimum* date.

```
select 
  min(created)
  'failure' as status,
  code,
  min(arena) as arena,
  count(case when status = 'failure' then 1 end) / count(*) * 100 as failed
from game_table
where some_condition
group by code;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get percentage of failure or success group by code like below.

```
 select DATE(created) as dt, count(case when status = "failure" then 1 end) * 100/count(status) as failure, code, arena, cnt
 from percent_issue group by code
```

Comment: @amit : -1, did you checked in your query where `dt` is coming from?

Comment: sorry dt should be replace with "DATE(created) as dt",
There is difference between my query and above query.

Comment: @sagi how come he copied ? look carefully , I can see the difference